# How to pass function parameter to url_for in script

Tags: javascript, python, flask

I am trying to pass parameter to `url_for` in script.

On my html code.

```
<div class="float-right">
    <a href="#" onclick="view_article('aaa')">click</a>
</div>
```

And for my script code.

```
function view_article(id){
    var w=700, h=1200, l=(screen.availWidth - w) / 2, t=(screen.availHeight - h) / 2;
    window.open("{{ url_for('articles.article_detail', articleId="+id+") }}","_blank","width= "+ w + ",height=" + h + ",left=" + l + ",top=" + t + ", scrollbars = yes, location = no, toolbar = no, menubar = no, status = no");
    };
```

And on my python code.

```
@articles.route("/article/detail/<articleId>", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def article_detail(articleId):
    return articleId
```

I expect to return `aaa`

But in this code, it returns `+id+`

I tried to use `articleId=id` instead of `articleId="+id_"`

But this also does not work...

Can anyone help?

Comment: You can't mix Javascript and Python code on the browser like that. Template tags (`{{ }}`) are computed on the server side then sent to the browser. You may try `window.open("/article/detail/" + id)` although it is not as portable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a fake article ID and replace it with the real id:

```
"{{ url_for('articles.article_detail', articleId=9999) }}".replace("9999", id)
```